# Twilio SMS Chatbot using imessage & imessage effects?

Tags: ios, sms, twilio, imessage

Does anyone know if it is possible to use those imessage effects (i.e. confetti, send with lasers) when sending a message via a twilio bot? So to add a "jazzy" effect to a chatbot, would love to use those fun effects.

Thanks!

Comment: No Twilio does not support this because Twilio sends messages as green, which is the universal signal for spam. But you can do that using the Messages app on your computer, which can programmed using Apple Script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio only sends SMS messages, not iMessages as Apple has not made that API public. Consequently you will notice that messages from Twilio numbers will appear  as green chat bubbles and cannot have any of the fancy iMessage effects.

Comment: Do any other hacks to imitate this feature?

Comment: Not as part of SMS!